# Scraping based on class name

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping

From here I would like to extract the address "Calle Tiera Del Soconusco No. 252".

```
<td class="type-address"><span>Calle Tiera Del Soconusco No. 252 </span></td>
```

I have tried the following codes but I fail to get the necessary information.

```
infor = response2.xpath("td[2]/td[contains(@class,'type-address')]").get()
infor2= response2.xpath("td[2]/@class").get()
```

Comment: Use `text()`: `response2.xpath("td[2]/td[contains(@class,'type-address')]/text()").get()`, If it doesn't work then please share the URL.

Comment: I tried the code but it does not work..! 
https://www.opensanctions.org/entities/Q16203688/
this is URL and can you help me scrap 'name'?

Comment: `response.xpath('//tbody//tr[2]/td//text()').get()`

Answer (score 0):

So the parent element is a `<td>` with a class of "type-address", then the parent element has a child `<span>` element that actually contains the text.

So try:

```
info = response.xpath('//td[@class="type-address"]/span/text()').get()

# or if there is more than 1

info = response.xpath('//td[@class="type-address"]/span/text()').getall()
```